# Live Streaming with Html5 <audio> tag

Tags: jquery, html, audio, stream

I have been searching for a fix for when a user presses pause on the player on my website, the stream needs to unload and when they press play again it plays the live stream at the correct place. Instead of buffering the stream while paused and continuing with the buffered stream. I found what looks like a fix on this forum but havent been able to see how to implement it properly.

The website player is @ http://vybzradio.co.uk/vybzradio_JplayerTEMP2.html

the code i used was this

```
var audio = $("audio").get(0);
audio.pause(0);
var tmp = audio.src;
audio.src = "";
audio.load();
$("audio").remove();

$("#audio-player").html("<audio controls preload='none'></audio>");<br>
audio = $("audio").get(0);
audio.src = tmp;
audio.addEventListener('pause', current-function);
```

Unsure where it goes or if its even correct. Can anyone help with this please ?

Thanks in advance

Rich Jacob